# php anonymous class extends dynamic

Tags: php, anonymous-class, extending-classes

anyone of you know how to get effect like in these code

```
 public function create(SomeInterface $obj)
 {
     $class = get_class($obj);
     return new class extends $class {
        //some magic here
     }
 }
```

Obvious that code will not work in PHP.
`$obj` can be an instance of many different classes.  I want to get an instance of class extending the $obj. (It will give me an ability to overload some basic methods)

Comment: This is obviously not a duplicate since PHP7 offers anonymous classes. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php

Comment: you right. anyway looks for me that the answer will be similar. only 'eval' but i don't want to use it...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Class dynamically extending in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883980/php-class-dynamically-extending-in-runtime)

Answer (score 2):

It is very possible with PHP 7+. Here is a really simple example:

```php
interface SomeInterface {};
class one implements SomeInterface {};
class two extends one {};

function create(SomeInterface $class) {
    $className = get_class($class);
    return eval("return (new class() extends $className {});");
}

$newTwoObj = create(new two());
```

Note that this is returning a new instance of the anonymous object. I don't believe there is any way to return a reference to the class (not instantiated).

Also note that this uses the `eval()` function, which I don't normally condone, but it is the only way I was able to find have a dynamically-assigned inheritance (without using `class_alias()` which could only be used once). You will want to be very careful and not allow unsanitized data to be passed in.